# How to scroll to a section when UITableViewCell has automatic height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` with multiple cell prototypes and automatic row height and multiple sections and rows.

Some sections has header view, others none.

`myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

I want to jump on the **10th** section, so I use:

`let section = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 9)
myTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(section, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)`

But it didn't work, because I think iOS cannot really know the 10th section start due on `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

What do you think? How can I scroll to a particular section while cells has variable content and height?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: let section = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 10) it will go to section  11 not 10, section starts from 0

Comment: @MikeAlter indeed, you're right, I just updated my post.

Comment: you should try it in main queue , and also post delegate methdos